# Dim screen without Dialog

Tags: android

I'm experiencing a very mysterious problem: when it's time to show a Dialog, screen dims, but Dialog itself does not appear. 
Full scenario of the problem:
I have a Dialog, that shows up on some condition (even if tablet\phone is asleep, I have AlarmManager set up). I launch my app, lock the screen and wait for event that shows the Dialog (the condition is "lost GPS coordinates"). So when the phone "looses" GPS connection, it launches AudioNotification alongside with the Dialog. So, when I hear this notification, I unlock my phone and see only dimmed screen but without a dialog.

I'd gladly provide some code but Im not sure what part of it could be usefull in such strange situation. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try adding log messages throughout the process - from the initial detection of the condition, to the triggering of the audio and creation and display of the dialog.  Then examine the log - you can probably even do so after the fact if you catch it before extraneous messages push yours out of the logcat buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not open the dialog if your activity/fragment not visible.

Check inside onResume() method whether dialogue must be displayed.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

    if(gpsLostErrorOccured()){
        showDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: how will it help me? If I just show dialog in onResume() method, it will be ok, isnt it?

Comment: if you phone is locked your activity is stopped and deactivated, so you can not open a dialog since it needs a valid and active context / activity

Comment: There are varieties of dialog which do not require that the owning app be between onPause and onResume - in fact they don't even require that the owning context be an Activity, though it must of course be a valid one.